# Why is merge() not working?

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to query a number of items form a larger dataset using:

```
output <- merge(TS_SECURITY_MASTER, mydata, by.x = "INSTRUMENT_ID", by.y = "SEC_ID")
```

the result is a dataframe with 0 rows.

If I query 1 item:

```
TS_SECURITY_MASTER[TS_SECURITY_MASTER$INSTRUMENT_ID == "BGG873000",]


> INSTRUMENT_ID             INVEST1_ID                INSTRUMENT_DESC INSTRUMENT_TYPE IV_TYPE               CREATED_DATE
153740     BGG873000 00386920 0000000000000 HONG KONG MORTG CP .99% 4/26/1              CP      CP 2017-04-21 09:54:34.445872
       ACTIVE_INDICATOR DESC_CHANGE_IND LAST_DESC_CHANGE_DATE RSK_CNTRY_CD CURRENCY_CODE          INV1_SHORT_DESC
153740                Y               N   2017-04-21 09:54:38           HK           HKD HONG KONG MTG CP .99% 18
                           INV1_LONG_DESC_L1 INV1_LONG_DESC_L2                      INV1_LONG_DESC_L3
153740 HONG KONG MORTGAGE CP .99% 26/04/2018              <NA> Hong Kong Mortgage CP 0.99% 26/04/2018
```

and in the other:

```
> mydata[mydata$SEC_ID == "BGG873000",]
factor(0)
61 Levels: BFJ190000
```

"BGG873000" is in both frames in the correct columns
I bet this is really simple but I can't understand the issue. Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Convert your merging variable into a character vector for both data.frames. Then give it a go.

Comment: Have you tried trimming the values in the `SEC_ID` column?

Comment: lots of spaces after my IDs  in mydata. thanks Barbara. I assumed .csv format trims these automatically.

Comment: If you set `strip.white = TRUE` when you use `read.csv` it will trim while it reads in, but the default is FALSE.

Comment: thank you Gregor that's very useful, I edited the csv and loaded back in.